# Adonis 5 build did not copy env file into build folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, backend, adonis.js

I used Adonis 5 in production, everytime I try `npm run build` .env file didn't copy into the build folder, is it still a bug?

Comment: I have the same issue. I just opened a thread on Github https://github.com/adonisjs/core/discussions/1874

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can modify the .adonisrc.json file in the "metaFiles" key

```
"metaFiles": [
".env",
".adonisrc.json",
{
  "pattern": "public/**",
  "reloadServer": false
},
{
  "pattern": "resources/views/**/*.edge",
  "reloadServer": false
}],
```

and then write the command `node ace build`

Comment: Yess.. it's work.. I just notice it lately.. thank you..

Answer (score 3):

[From the founder of Adonis](https://github.com/adonisjs/core/discussions/1874#discussioncomment-123731):

> This is intentional since you are not supposed to use your development .env file in production.

This means that now, you have to run this command `cp .env build/.env` before starting the process or it will not work.

Comment: Thank u, yes I did it in my project, and it's work. But any updates for the released adonis 5 versions? hopefully, they can give a new update to make this more simple.

Comment: @Felixganiharris Adonis 5 is already released and stable. I am using it in production.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone around it by using "postbuild": "@powershell copy '.env' 'build/.env'"
when debugging on windows. Not the most elegant but it works to debug node.js typescript with adonisjs 5 on Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Yeah this is what I've experienced too.

Comment: @XxXk5XxX This is an issue that can be circumvented by adding the .env file to the metaFiles node in adonissrc.json while you're working. Remember to remove it once you push